# Objective C Pointer to pointer in method memory error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I want to return 2 objects from a method so i obviously set a method which return NSDictionary and NSIndexPath by reference, it shouldn't be hard but from some reason I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error after the method finished and returned.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)sortedMessagesUnreadIndexPath:(NSIndexPath **)indexPathForUnreadMessage
{
    ...
    if (indexPathForUnreadMessage != NULL)
        *indexPathForUnreadMessage = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:array.count-1 inSection:dict.count-1];
    ...
    return dict;
}

// the call

NSIndexPath *unreadIndexPath = NULL;
self.messages = [self.conversation sortedMessagesUnreadIndexPath:&unreadIndexPath]; 
// EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here AFTER the method return

self.unreadIndexPath = unreadIndexPath;
```

***EDIT***
using ARC, iOS 7 SDK, Xcode 5

Comment: yes, sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: I just check your code and it works fine. I believe the issue is happening in part of your method you haven't show.

Comment: yes Greg you are right. the problem in my method is that I alloc/init the given indexPath inside "enumerateWithBlock..." of NSArray.
I fixed it by setting a __block object outside of the enumeration and then set the reference to point to that object.
Thanks :)